# Issue while trying to update a database

Tags: python, database, sqlalchemy

I'm working using python and a relational databases with many tables, I'm using the AGENTS one.

The goal is to write a Python application able to load the actual content of the AGENTS table in memory, storing it using a Pandas Dataframe. The application should also support some functions:

# Loads in memory the content of table AGENTS, saving it in a new Pandas DataFrame

load_agents()

# Change the working area for a particular agent, whose code has been specified as input set_agent_working_area()

I have already wrote all of them but  just the last one is not working properly it I have the error: Error while updating working area of A003: execute() got an unexpected keyword argument 'WORKING_AREA_AGENT'

here a snapshot of the table:

[image]

This is the code that I wrote and I expect that when i use the last function I will update the working area variable of my table but is not working.

```
import pandas as pd
!pip install mysqlclient
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.sql import text


# Loads in memory the content of table AGENTS, saving it in a new Pandas DataFrame
def load_agents():
  sql = 'SELECT AGENT_CODE, AGENT_NAME,WORKING_AREA,COMMISSION, PHONE_NO FROM AGENTS'

  agents = []

  rs = con.execute(text(sql))
  # If there is one more row to read, fetchone will return such a row
  # otherwise, it will return None
  row = rs.fetchone()
  while(row is not None):
    agent= (row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4])
    agents.append(agent)
    row = rs.fetchone()
  
  agents= pd.DataFrame(agents, columns=['AGENT_CODE','AGENT_NAME','WORKING_AREA_AGENT','COMMISSION','PHONE_NUMBER'])
  # Instead of the automatic index generated by Pandas, we use the agent code
  return agents.set_index('AGENT_CODE')

def set_agent_working_area(ac, new_working_area):
    agents=load_agents()
    sql = 'UPDATE AGENTS SET WORKING_AREA=:WORKING_AREA_AGENT WHERE AGENT_CODE=:AGENT_CODE'

    try:
        con.execute(text(sql), WORKING_AREA_AGENT=new_working_area, AGENT_CODE=ac)
        print(f'The working area of {ac} has been set to {new_working_area}')
    except Exception as e:
        print(f'Error while updating working area of {ac}: {e}')

    # We apply the same modification to the Pandas DataFrame
    agents.loc[ac, 'WORKING_AREA_AGENT'] = new_working_area

test the last function:
#we will update the working area for a specific agent code: ac

set_agent_working_area('A003','Barcelona')
I have the error: Error while updating working area of A003: execute() got an unexpected keyword argument 'WORKING_AREA_AGENT'
```

I have already modify multiple time my code but It still gives error: someone has a better idea how to handle that error?

Thanks

Comment: You have given a whole load of code, most probably irrelevant, but not actually told us the error. We can't guess at it. Please give a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass the bound parameters individually to `execute` (like you've seen). You should have them in a dictionary:

```py
con.execute(text(sql), {WORKING_AREA_AGENT: new_working_area, AGENT_CODE: ac})
```